# Openldap + dynlist + posixGroup

Tags: linux, ldap, debian, openldap

I have problem with OpenLdap and permission to file.

First - I set this in my slapd.conf:

```
overlay         dynlist
dynlist-attrset labeledURIObject labeledURI
```

Second - I make cn=test,ou=Projects,dc=example,dc=com with:

```
dn: cn=test,ou=Projects,dc=example,dc=com
gidNumber: 6789
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
objectClass: labeledURIObject
labeledURI: ldap:///cn=testgroup,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com?memberUid?sub?
(objectClass=posixGroup)
memberUid: user1 (dynamic)
memberUid: user2 (dynamic)
```

in `cn=testgroup,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com` i have memberuid: user1 and memberUid: user2

Third - when i made getent group test I have:

```
test:*:6789:user1,user2
```

But when I try id user1 i didn't see this group :(

And next I set `chmod 770 dir` and `chown root.test dir` and try access to this dir.

But of course it is not possible because the user is not in this group (that said "id").

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> *Third - when i made getent group test I have:*
>
> *test:*:6789:user1,user2*
>
> *But when i try id user1 i didn't see this group :(*

Unfortunately dynamic lists (*dynlists*) are ONE WAY groups (not TWO way).  This means that reverse lookups won't work, which causes the very issue you are now facing. There is no way to make reverse posix group lookups work with *dynlist*.

HOWEVER, there is another module available somewhere on OpenLDAP's site I believe.  It is called *autogroup*.  This is a static-group maintainer module.  This method of grouping does not involved dynamic data, rather it is REAL data that is automagically managed by the *autogroup* module.  However, it is configured similar to a *dynlist* group as it uses the *labeledURI* attribute to allow a "stored procedure" so to speak.

I too was disappointed when I realized the shortcomings of *dynlist*, and I should point out that *autogroup* is still somewhat experimental.  Test thoroughly and report any bugs to OpenLDAP.

I hope this helps...

Max

Answer (score 0):

Groups are constructed here in this way without `memberUid`, but `member`:

```
dn: cn=mygroup,ou=groups,o=company
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: mygroup
member: uid=user1,ou=users,o=company
displayName: mygroup
gidNumber: 1234
```

The schema type is also to be set to RFC2307bis (`ldap_schema = rfc2307bis` in `sssd.conf`).

Comment: Ok, but I have one problem when I tried add group like yours: additional info: invalid structural object class chain (posixGroup/groupOfNames)

Answer (score 0):

For the 3rd issue, the problem is that id will use a ldap request with (member=uid=login,... ) while getent group will search for the group ( cn=groupname ). So the 2nd one trigger the overlay , while the first don't ( see the man page ). I also faced the issue, and found some links about it :
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200708/msg00250.html and http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-devel/200708/msg00127.html.

So far, I didn't found any good solution, maybe changing nss_ldap would work ( if you use it, which you didn't explained )

Comment: For what it is worth, I found out that nss-ldap would work fine if you place another group in member, and would do what I wanted ( ie, nested group ). I am not sure if this is what you wanted but I hope that may help.